# to get better my custom def for validate login

Tags: mysql, django

i have a custom function for validate my login:

```
def validate(request):

    if request.method=='POST':
        user = request.POST.get('user')
        pass = request.POST.get('pass')
        pass_enc = md5.new(pass).hexdigest()

        try:
            #validar si es admin
            usuarioAdmin = User.objects.get(user=user, pass=pass_enc, tipe=1, state=1)
            request.session['nameUser'] = user.name
            request.session['levelUser'] = "admin"

            return redirect('home')

        except User.DoesNotExist:

            message= "User/Password wrong !!"
            context = {
                'message': message,
            }

            return render(request, 'login.html', context)
```

on my home view:

```
@login_required
def home(request):

    template = loader.get_template('administrator/index.html')
    context = {
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

for validate @login_required:

```
def login_required(f):
    def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'nameUser' not in request.session.keys() :
            return redirect('logout')
        return f(request, *args, **kwargs)
    wrap.__doc__=f.__doc__
    wrap.__name__=f.__name__
    return wrap
```

maybe any suggest or link for create my custom login and validate different tipes users(admin, comun user...etc..)
thanks !!

Comment: Why are you doing this at all? All you've done is re-implement Django's login, but in a much much less secure fashion (plain MD5 is not at all safe). Stop doing this, and let Django handle it for you.

Comment: thanks for your suggest